# remove all instances of words in array out of string

Tags: php, regex, string

I am wondering what is the best way to do the following in PHP.

I have an array of words to ignore and I want to remove all instances of those words out of a string. But it has to words regardless what the words that are each an element in the array are.

An example:

If the array is:

```
$ignoreList = array(
    "1" => "one",
    "2" => "at",
    "3" => "chicken",
    "4" => "the"
);
```

and the string is

```
$str = "The one quick brown fox, at the farm, jumped over the lazy dog and ate a chicken";
```

after this operation, the string would be "quick brown fox, farm, jumped over lazy dog and ate a".

The string doesn't have to contain those words, but if it does then they are removed.

How would one do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a quick regex:

```
$str = preg_replace('/\b('. implode('|',$ignoreList) .')\b/i', '', $str);
```

`\b` are word delimiters.

Comment: could you explain to me exactly what this does. Like if I was 5. I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: I'd suggest you take a tour of regex first at http://www.regular-expressions.info/. It will become much easier to understand after you learn the basics. If you know what `implode` does then all you need is the regex part. `preg_replace` simply replaces what the regex matches with nothing in this case.

Comment: ah, okay. what does implode do?

Comment: "implode — Join array elements with a string", so the output will be the following string - one|at|chicken|the. by the way, for these type of questions you can easily use google.

Comment: you need to wrap the group of words in parens. What you have now is basically saying `\bone` OR `at` OR `chicken` OR `the\b`

Comment: @CrayonViolent: +1. Or `implode` on `'\b|\b'`